# How to uninstall QGIS 3.8 from MacOS in a clean way?

Tags: qgis, macos

I have two installations of QGIS, 3.14 and 3.8, I want to uninstall 3.8. What is the proper way to do it? Do [these instructions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268229/how-to-uninstall-qgis-from-macos) also apply to this newer version?

The following are the paths that the Python interpreter sees:

```
/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python
/Users/my_user/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
/Users/my_user/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins
/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins
/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/site-packages
/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7
/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geos
/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Resources/python
/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python37.zip
/Users/my_user/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
```

Those that are not in `/Applications/QGIS3.8.ap` are common to both installations.

Comment: An answer to your question was on another thread https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/296645