# Temporal/Spectral Profile Tool: Python error - QGIS 3.16 macOS Catalina

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, error, scp

"[Temporal/Spectral Profile Tool](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/temporalprofiletool/)"-plugin runs into a Python error (below: reports import error in last two lines, entire error message is 14 lines):

QGIS 3.16.13 on mac 10.15.7, running Qt 5.14.2, QWT 6.1.4.
In QGIS 3.10 the plugin runs properly.

I haven't found any earlier posts on this issue.

Error message:

```
_import
  mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Pillow-7.2.0-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg/PIL/_imaging.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libxcb.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Pillow-7.2.0-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg/PIL/_imaging.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 0):

CResolved: complete [uninstall](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268229/how-to-uninstall-qgis-from-macos) and [reinstall](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366848/scp-plugin-for-qgis-3-10-on-mac) to [alternative build](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html) QGIS 3.16.8 while solving an issue with [Semi-Automatic Classification](https://semiautomaticclassificationmanual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation_mac.html) plugin fixed also the issue with the Temporal/Spectral Profile Tool. Thanks to KyngChaos, [Albert van Niekerk](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/48519/albert-van-niekerk) and [Rachel](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/98391/rachel).